# The signficance of {} in Update MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

From the Definitive Guide:

```
db.lists.insert({"todo" : ["dishes", ""laundry", "dry cleaning"]})
```

Performing the $pull

```
db.lists.update( {} , {"$pull": {"todo" : "laundry"}})
```

What is the significance of the leading empty brackets? Why does it have to be there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to [`update`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) specifies the selection criteria for the update. It identifies which documents to apply the update to.

When an empty object `{}` is passed, that means that the update should be applied to all documents in the collection.